# disable maven release plugin defined in parent pom

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin

I am new to maven. I have product structure as following

```
myWebProduct
    pom.xml
    coreModule
    webModule
    htmlTestModule
```

The  maven release plugin is defined at  the company level of `pom.xml` file which is parent of `myWebProduct`.  It has set release plugin run default goals of `deploy` and default preparationGoals `clean verify install`.

I want to release product in `myWebProduct` level which works fine except I would like to skip release the `htmlTestModule`. Because `deploy` life cycle on `htmlTestModule` will cause  deployment of war file to remote Tomcat servers and I don’t want this happening during release.

I tried to add following in `pom.xml` of the `htmlTestModule`.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1</version>    
  <configuration>
    <skip>true</skip>
    <preparationGoals>clean validate</preparationGoals>
    <goals>testCompile</goals>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But when running 'mvn release:perform' at `myWebProduct`.  I have seen the deploy goal was still executed on `htmlTestModule`. Could anyone help with this?

And I also tried  following on `htmlTestModule`:

```
<plugins>           
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>      
    <executions>
      <execution>
      <id>donotRunMe</id>
      <phase>none</phase>
    </execution>                    
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Still, the deploy goal always executed in `htmlTestModule`.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you're taking the wrong approach here. Let me explain.

The `deploy` phase of maven is not meant to mean deploy to a remote server or anything like this. This is meant to be deploy to a remote repository.

Hence I believe you shouldn't try to skip the deploy phase in your module, but un-tie the deployment to a remote Tomcat server from the `deploy` phase, by making it a specific goal for example.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I had tied my deploy war file to remort tomcat server at prepare-package-phase since my test goal depends on that. What is your suggestion for this kind testing package?

Comment: Well it all depends but my general rule is that my build should be self contained, including (integration) testing. 

So I'd look in deploying in a local (to the build) Tomcat instance (using the Cargo or Tomcat plugin for example) and test there. This way your build doesn't depend on any external resource that needs a specific configuration.

If that takes too much time to run for releases, then I suggest you find a way to just skip the testing on the tomcat instance, but not the full deploy phase.

Also the best phase for this testing is probably the integration-test phase.

HTH.